# I am trying to run older VC++ code in 2010VC++ I am getting error C387 error

Tags: c++-cli

```
this->InitButton->Location = System::Drawing::Point(24, 8);
this->InitButton->Name = S"InitButton";
this->InitButton->Size = System::Drawing::Size(184, 24);
this->InitButton->TabIndex = 0;
this->InitButton->Text = S"Initialize NMC Network";

// this give an error
this->InitButton->Click += new System::EventHandler(this, InitButton_Click);
```

Comment: And what error are you getting, exactly? "C387" is not a VC++ error code.

Comment: Raj, why don't you provide more information? I searched for the error and I didn't see anything. What is the error? Are you sure the number is correct? As far as I have noticed VS number consists of 5-6 digits. How old is the code (i.e. which VS version)? Which VS are you using now?

Answer (score 2):

```
this->InitButton->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, InitButton_Click);
```

That's C3867, not C387.  You have to specify the class name with the method name in C++/CLI.  It's syntax for assigning delegates is quite unlike the one in the C# language, there's no syntax sugar at all.  This isn't otherwise associated with VS2010, it fails to compile in earlier editions too.  Fix:

```
this->InitButton->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::InitButton_Click);
```

Replace *Form1* with the name of your Form derived class.  You don't actually need & but it is boilerplate in the designer generated code.  Letting the designer generate this code is the best way to keep out of trouble.

Comment: `gcnew` is the correct way to allocate instances of a ref class, like `System::EventHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Hans's answer concerning the correct way to get a pointer-to-member for delegate construction, C++/CLI does not use the S prefix on managed strings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
You are right about the error code (typo).  I was able to compile is with warning now.  I made some changes.
Changed common language run time support to old syntax and was able to compile and run it.

Common Language Runtime Support, Old Syntax (/clr:oldSyntax)